# Check boxes on same horizontal row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like to display all the check boxes on the same horizontal row as described [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline).

My attempt so far has resulted in vertical stacking:

http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/5536/

```
    <form>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">1</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">2</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3" disabled>
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox3">3 (disabled)</label>
      </div>
    </form>
```

[image]

Comment: The class "form-check-inline" for your div with class "form-check" should do the trick. otherwise set it to inline-block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Bootstrap (as seen in your screenshot) then the class "form-check-inline" should work. If not, you're missing some bootstrap styles.

If bootstrap is not what you're using, you could simply do it this way:

```
.form-check {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I've updated your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2svpjc5b/

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4. Your inline css works perfectly, but I would love to know why its not working as a result of the Bootstrap form-check-inline tag?

Comment: Please take a look in your Browser Tools, if there are any styles added for form-check-inline, if not, maybe there are missing in your css!?

Answer (score 0):

Add styling to all your div tags. `<div class="form-check form-check-inline" style="display:inline">`

Comment: With that class added, I don't think inline style is needed.